# How to return multiple values of String that are present in an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array.

eg. `var ratio = ["Net Sales", "Total Sales", "Profit", "Day's Sale", "Average", "Sum"]`

I want to return all the values that are present in this array when compared with the string.

String eg :

```js
var str = "ABC of [Net Sales = Total Sales (Profit)]"
```

My final output should be: `["Net Sales", "Total Sales", "Profit"]`

I have tried to use some() but it only returns a boolean.

```
var stringIncludesItem = ratio.some(item => str.includes(item));
```

Comment: `some` is used to know wheather element is present or not, Use `filter` instead

Answer (score -1):

[`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) only returns true when at least one of the items returns true for the condition imposed. [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) filters out (removes, but not from the original array) elements that do not return true for the condition imposed.

```
var ratio = ["Net Sales", "Total Sales", "Profit", "Day's Sale", "Average", "Sum"];
var str = "ABC of [Net Sales = Total Sales (Profit)]";
var stringIncludesItem = ratio.filter(item => str.includes(item));
```

Comment: Problem with this is that for eg. var ratio = ["Net Sales", "Net Sales1", "Net", "Sales"] and my string eg. var str = "Net sales1". Then this will return all the values present in ratio. How do I only get Net Sales1?

Comment: Your code returns a boolean which doesn't match the expected output.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote a typo!

Answer (score -1):

Use `filter`:

```js
var ratio = ["Net Sales", "Total Sales", "Profit", "Day's Sale", "Average", "Sum"];
var str = "ABC of [Net Sales = Total Sales (Profit)]";
var stringIncludesItem = ratio.filter(item => str.includes(item));
console.log(stringIncludesItem)
```

Comment: Problem with this is that for eg. var ratio = ["Net Sales", "Net Sales1", "Net", "Sales"] and my string eg. var str = "Net sales1". Then this will return all the values present in ratio. How do I only get Net Sales1?

Comment: @Umang Im sorry I dont understand your follow up question. This answer gives the exact output your question asked for, if there is some further detail this is missing please edit it into your question and ill update the answer.

Comment: @Umang How should the filter work? If you want to return an array then how is it supposed to discriminate the value? Should it match the whole string? Does it match the longest one? Let's say you have `var ratio = ["Net Sales", "Net Sales1", "Net", "Sales"]` why should it match `"Net Sales"` and not both `"Net"` and `"Sales"`?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to grab the strings you need:

```js
const arr = ["Net Sales", "Total Sales", "Profit", "Day's Sale", "Average", "Sum"];

const str = "ABC of [Net Sales = Total Sales (Profit)]";

const regex = new RegExp(arr.join('|'), 'g');

console.log(str.match(regex));
```